# Refreshing cache of AWS FileGateWay

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-storage-gateway

I am trying to **refresh cache** on **AWS FileGateway**. I have built the AWSStorageGateway using **AWSStorageGatewayClientBuilder** object like this -

```
AWSStorageGateway awsStorageGateway = AWSStorageGatewayClientBuilder.standard()
                .withRegion(region)
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
                .build();
```

Also, I am using this to build the ARN -

```
RefreshCacheRequest refreshCacheRequest = new RefreshCacheRequest();
refreshCacheRequest.setFileShareARN("arn:aws:storagegateway:"+region+":"+awsId+":"+shareID);
```

ARN is of the format,

```
arn:aws:storagegateway:region:account-id:share/share-id
```

Finally, I am refreshing the cache like this 0

```
awsStorageGateway.refreshCache(refreshCacheRequest);
```

I am getting this exception -

```
com.amazonaws.services.storagegateway.model.AWSStorageGatewayException: User: arn:aws:iam::12345:user/system/func-user is not authorized to perform: storagegateway:RefreshCache on resource: arn:aws:storagegateway:region:account-id:share-id (Service: AWSStorageGateway; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID:request ID)
```

Am I missing anything here?

I am pretty sure IAM access key which I have has the previlages.

PS - account-id which I have given is the Access Key of IAM

Comment: update: I had to change URN to proper format as mentioned here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html and FGW was refreshed